# Обмен данными между родительским и дочерним процессом в Python

Tags: python, процесс

Добрый день. Есть родительский и дочерний процессы. Дочерний создан модулем subprocess. Возможен ли кросс-платформенный способ постоянного обмена данными между этими процессами?

Comment: Странный вопрос... Если не используется платформо-специфичный код, то не вижу никаких объективных причин для появления проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте внимательно:

> communicate(input=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process terminate.  The optional input argument should be a string to besent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent tothe child.
>
> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr).
>
> Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

В общем, communicate сам закрывает потоки и ждет, когда процесс завершится. Лучше вручную отправлять данные в stdin процесса и потом считывать его stdout.

Comment: А не подскажите, где можно подробнее ознакомиться с нюансами записи и чтения при работе с каналами - пока у меня все подвисает в ожидании. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ну ситуация примерно такая: между процессами создается 2 pipe-а.
Pipe(труба) -- это что-то типа буффера с ограниченным размером и двумя концами. Один конец есть у твоего процесса, другой у дочернего. Если ты скармливаешь данные в Pipe, который присоединен к stdin-у дочернего процесса, а он в свою очередь пытается выводить данные на свой stdout, то оба пайпа могут заполниться и у тебя все повиснет.

Comment: спасибо - теперь уже начинаю понимать )

Comment: 2illya_tt Лучше все-же вместо обмена сообщениями через пайпы взят кошерные корутины(они асинхронны по определению) и не иметь проблем. Ваш подход это жуткий велосипедизм и незнание возможностей языка.

Comment: Да, незнание возможностей языка к сожалению присутствует. Вам спасибо, сегодня открыл для себя сопрограммы. Однако для моих целей они несколько не подходят. Нужно именно создание нового процесса и постоянная поддержка связи с ним. Спасибо за ответы )

Answer (score 0):

Для обмена между процессами и даже на разных хостах в Python есть библиотечка memcached

## memcache библиотека позволяет иметь общуюю переменную или объект для разных процессов и даже если они работают на разных компютерах

## Установка memcache   'sudo apt-get install memcached python3-memcache' (для Python3)

## Если процессы использующие переменную работают на одном хосте, то адрес сервера serverIP будет 127.0.0.1   port 11211 задан по умолчанию.

## Если переменную используют процессы на разных хостах клиент сервер то нужно выбрать внешний адрес сервера,

## На сервере открыть файл sudo nano /etc/memcached.con  в файле найти строчку 'l 127.0.0.1' и заменить на внешний адрес сервера сохранить файл.

## Перезапустить процесс  'sudo systemctl restart memcached', порт 11211 должен быть открыт на вход и на выход для TCP

## Открыть порт на сервере Linux командами 'sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 --j ACCEPT'   и   'sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 --j ACCEPT'

## На сервере

`import memcache
shared = memcache.Client(['serverIP:11211'], debug=0) #Задаем общую область памяти на сервере с адресом
shared.set('Value', 'Hello')                          #задаем переменную Value и присваиваем ей значение Hello`

На клиенте

`import memcache
shared = memcache.Client(['serverIP:11211'], debug=0)    #Подключаем клиента к зашаренной области памяти сервера
print shared.get('Value')                                # считываем значение переменной Value с сервера и печатаем
shared.set('Value', 'Good Bue')                          # задаем новое значение переменной Value 
print shared.get('Value')                               # вновь считываем значение переменной Value с сервера и печатаем`